# trigger CSS animations onlcick

Tags: html, css, animation, onclick, css-animations

I have created an animation for an element on my page and it always runs when the page is refreshed but i would like the animation to play when an element is clicked. How would i go about doing this?

CSS:

```
#login-or-signup-selection {
    display: flex;
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
}

@keyframes test {
    0% {top: 0px;}
    50% {top:300px}
    100% {top: 0;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="clickMe">Element to click</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function () { 
  $(this).addClass('login-or-signup-selection');
  $(this).on("animationend", function(event) {
    $(this).removeClass('login-or-signup-selection')
  });
});
```

```css
.login-or-signup-selection {
    display: flex;
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
}

@keyframes test {
    0% {top: 0px;}
    50% {top:300px}
    100% {top: 0;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="clickMe">Element to click</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need some JavaScript for this.

First off, separate the CSS `animation` properties, and anything else related to your animation, and add them to their own class.

Next up, the JavaScript. You'll want to add an event listener to your element to add the animation class when clicked, and a timeout to remove the class afterwards so it will animate when clicked again.

```js
const yourElement = document.getElementById('clickMe');
yourElement.addEventListener('click', _=> {
  yourElement.classList.add('animation-class');
  setTimeout(
    _=> yourElement.classList.remove('animation-class'),
    5000
  )
});
```

```css
#clickMe {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
}

.animation-class {
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes test {
    0% { top: 0px; }
    50% { top: 300px; }
    100% { top: 0; }
}
```

```html
<p id="clickMe">Element to click</p>
```

Comment: This will only work once. Subsequent clicks will have no effect.

Comment: @AHaworth Good catch. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only css and don't even care about js onclick events for now,

## use the `:active` pseudo selector.

The only downside is that it only plays while (=during) e.g. the mouse button **is** down.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for this.

If you add an event listener on the p element to listen for a click, this can then add the animation name to the selection div.

But you need to also listen for the end of the animation, otherwise subsequent clicks will have no effect. On animation end this snippet removes the animation name.

Note also that in order to be absolutely sure that the first (onload) animation end is trapped, the first animation name is not set until the event listeners have been set up.

```js
function init() {
  const clickMe = document.querySelector('#clickMe');
  const selection = document.querySelector('#login-or-signup-selection');
  clickMe.addEventListener('click', function() {
    selection.style.animationName = 'test';
  });
  selection.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    selection.style.animationName = '';
  });
  selection.style.animationName = 'test';
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
#login-or-signup-selection {
  display: flex;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 300px
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="clickMe">Element to click</p>
<div id="login-or-signup-selection">Login or signup selection</div>
```