# How to reset the opacity of an image after pressing?

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my page representing an up arrow and, which is used to jump to the top of the page thanks to a link). This image has an opacity of "0.2", and "1" when hovering over it with the mouse.
From a smartphone or tablet, when you press on this image, the opacity remains at "1".
I would like this opacity to return to "0.2" after pressing this one.
How to do please?

My HTML code :

```
<a href="#top"><img src="./img/up.png" alt="up" title="up"></a>
```

My CSS code :

```
a > img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
a > img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: move the opacity to a different css class. Add or  remove that class from the HTML element when required.

Comment: Just to check - you want it so when the user has a finger or pointing device actually over the element you want it to remain at opacity 1 but as soon as the finger/device is removed you want it to go to opacity 0.2. Is that right? Investigate touchstart etc.

Comment: Yes A Harworth, You understood exactly ;)

Comment: You need some JavaScript to sense touch events.

Comment: It is not exactly the same, but it can also be achieved without using javascript using `css animation` and `css keyframes`

Comment: Great minds think alike, @Gurgolo - `CSS Animation` is my go-to solution for implementing `:hover` effects on touchscreens too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `Javascript/Jquery`

I modified an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268536/trigger-css-animations-onlcick/73268713#73268713) of mine of few days ago

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function () { 
  $(this).addClass('tothetop');
  $(this).on("animationend", function(event) {
    $(this).removeClass('tothetop')
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  opacity:0.2;
} 

.tothetop {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes test {
  50% {opacity:1;}
  100% {opacity:0.2;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="clickMe" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```

A solution using only `CSS`

```css
@keyframes move {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

img {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity:0.2;
}

img:hover {
  animation: move 2s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```

Comment: Comprehensive answer. +1. Honestly though, in 2022, I wouldn't be using jQuery `$('#clickMe').click [...]` above JS `document.querySelector('#clickMe).addEventListener('click' [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

### A Pure CSS Solution without JavaScript

The problem lies with how best to implement `:hover` on interfaces where the user is not using a cursor controlled by a mouse or trackpad or a keyboard.

There isn't (yet) a perfect way to do this.

It doesn't exist, but we could imagine that the touchscreen counterpart to:

```
my-div:hover
```

might be:

```
my-div:touch
```

where the `:hover` behaviour is displayed for a second or two and then no longer displayed.

---

In the absence of a hypothetical `:touch` pseudo-class however, we can nevertheless implement one - and in CSS alone, without using JavaScript.

We can do this by introducing an `animation` for touchscreens - something like this:

```
@keyframes hoverForTouchScreens {
    
  0%, 50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

We can also ensure that this animation *only fires on touchscreens* with a `@media query`:

```
@media screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {

  a > img:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    animation: hoverForTouchScreens 2s ease-out;
  }
}
```

---

**Working Example**

Putting it all together:

```css
a > img {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

a > img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

a > img.touchscreen-simulation:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  animation: hoverForTouchScreens 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes hoverForTouchScreens {
        
  0%, 50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {

  a > img:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    animation: hoverForTouchScreens 2s ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#top">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/120/120" alt="up" title="up">
  <img class="touchscreen-simulation" src="https://picsum.photos/120/120" alt="up" title="up">
</a>

<p>The <code>@media query</code> won't be active on non-touch screens, so the <strong>image on the right</strong> is set up to simulate what <em>would</em> happen on a touchscreen in this setup.</p>
```

---

**Working Example:**